# Creating a bootstrap3 square tiled layout with centered content and multiple lines of content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a bootstrap3 square tiled layout with centered content and multiple lines of content.

Followed a couple other exchange answers and got this far:

[Booply](http://www.bootply.com/YnGyivrHQ3)

The only thing that is eluding me is how to center the content that breaks onto multiple lines.

Any thoughts?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-2 employee-home-link hidden-xs"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 portal-link ">
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <a href="" class="tile">Share Point</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 portal-link ">
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <a href="" class="tile">LinkedIn</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 portal-link  portal">
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <a href="" class="tile">Web Portal</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 portal-link ">
            <div class="dummy"></div>
            <a href="" class="tile">Live Chat</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 employee-home-link hidden-xs"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.portal-link.portal > .tile {background-color:#255a25;}

.dummy {
    margin-top: 100%;
}
.tile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: calc(50% - 55px);
    line-height: 35px;
    background-color: #1f476e;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.tile:hover, .tile:focus, .tile:active {
    color:#e76c0e;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.portal-link.portal > .tile:hover, .portal-link.portal > .tile:focus, .portal-link.portal > .tile:active {
    color:#8ccafe;
}
```

Comment: It's already centered inside the box, example "Web Portal". Not really sure what you are looking for...

Comment: the double line items are, but the single line entries are not centered.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: the css tricks solution requires us setting the height and width of the tiles ... that won't work with a responsive layout.

Answer (score 0):

I made this work by adding a new class for dual line text and adding a break to the text.

```
.shift
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    clear:both;
    padding-top:30px;
}

<div class="col-sm-2 survey-link ">
   <div class="dummy"></div>           
<a href="" class="tile shift">B03<br /> 2015-04</a>
```